# Python - decode or regex?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have this `dict` being scraped from the web, but it comes with this `unicode` issue:

```
{'track': [u'\u201cAnxiety\u201d',
           u'\u201cLockjaw\u201d [ft. Kodak Black]',
           u'\u201cMelanin Drop\u201d',
           u'\u201cDreams\u201d',
           u'\u201cIntern\u201d',
           u'\u201cYou Don\u2019t Think You Like People Like Me\u201d',
           u'\u201cFirst Day Out tha Feds\u201d',
           u'\u201cFemale Vampire\u201d',
           u'\u201cGirlfriend\u201d',
           u'\u201cOpposite House\u201d',
           u'\u201cGirls @\u201d [ft. Chance the Rapper]',
           u'\u201cI Am a Nightmare\u201d']}
```

which is the best way of stripping out these characters, using `regex`, or is there some `decode` method?

and how?

Comment: Those are left and right curly quotes. Do you actually want to remove all curly quote characters from your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are quotes (“ and ”). If you just want to get rid of them at the beginning or end of the string, it is easiest to `strip` them.

```
>>> u'\u201cAnxiety\u201d'.strip(u'\u201c\u201d')
u'Anxiety'
```

If you want to get rid of them anywhere in the string, `replace` them:

```
>>> u'\u201cAnxiety\u201d'.replace(u'\u201c', '').replace(u'\u201d', '')
u'Anxiety'
```

Comment: Or you could replace with regular quotes: `u'\u201cAnxiety\u201d'.replace(u'\u201c', '"').replace(u'\u201d', '"')`

Comment: @elethan Yes, that is also an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict['track'] = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\u201c','').replace('\u201d',''), dict['track']))
```

Better readable solution (in my opinion):

```
dict['track'] = [x.replace(u'\u201c', '').replace(u'\u201d', '') for x in dict['track']]
```

Quick explanation: `dict['track']`, the first only value in the `a` dictionary, is a list of strings, each has unnecessary `u'\u201c'` and `u'\u201d'`.
We use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) in Python to iterate through that list, and for every string in that list `x` replace its `u'\u201c'` and `u'\u201d'` by blank string `''`, which makes them disappear.

If you had more than one value in your dictionary, or other key other than `'track'`, and wanted to make this code a bit more generic and work for every dictionary with any key names, we can iterate through the values in the dictionary, and apply the above code to all the dictionary's values:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    dict[k] = [x.replace(u'\u201c', '').replace(u'\u201d', '') for x in v]
```

Comment: an explanation of how your answer addresses the problem would be useful.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Hope it's better now.